# Is it possible to setup PM2 auto-restart without sudo access?

Tags: node.js, terminal, hosting, sudo, pm2

I'm using Bluehost (not VPS or dedicated) for a Node app, and I'm able to setup PM2 and run my app (via SSH), but I want the app to auto restart when the server restarts. After running `pm2 startup systemd`, I get the following output:

```
[PM2] [ERROR] Init system not found
[PM2] To setup the Startup Script, copy/paste the following command: 
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/home4/myapp/bin /home4/myapp/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
startup systemd -u cheflyfe --hp /home4/myapp
```

The problem is that sudo is not enabled on my system, so I can't run the `sudo env` command. Is there still a way to auto-start PM2 with the server? If not, is there a way to do this without PM2? Should I just go for a different hosting provider?

Comment: Considering there's great VPS products available starting at $5/mo. or less if you count Amazon's free EC2 tier for new customers, there's really no reason to be stuck with something that doesn't give you the tools you want. Since you're paying for Bluehost, why not ask their customer support if they have a solution before evaluating other options?

Comment: Bluehost customer support won't get into anything technical. It seems that the service is designed for PHP, HTML, and Wordpress. I'm doing this project for a client who has Bluehost, so I'll try and get them to switch if there's no solution.

Comment: You're probably way out of their strike zone. If you're on a budget, don't forget many big providers have very generous credits available to new customers that might mean you get better service for free for a year or two.